# Receiving an event that occurs in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for my english this is a google traductor

I come from java and i am newbie in javascript.

In java you can create a listener in a class and get that event in other class... How can i do that??

server.js

```
user = 'sdfsdf123123';
if(ohhh_a_new_user) {
   console.log('new user.... run');
   // here i want call something with the param 'user'
} else {
   console.log('this is an old user... nothing');
}
```

main.js

```
var server = new SERVER(); 
server.listen(2000); // <- own function
server.event(NAME_OF_EVENT, user) {
  alert('the new user is a' + user)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Where in your `server.js` file are you defining the `SERVER` constructor?

Comment: yes i did.............

Comment: Please don't add tags to the question title.

Comment: Would you mind to show us that definition?